# Jquery - How to crop a image and scale it same size as the original image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to crop a image from original image by giving (xAxis, yAxis, Height, Width).

[image: small image of red panda]

all the cropped image should just as big as the boxes belows

[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iiue9.png)

and make the cropped part to a fix size so I can show those cropped image orderly on the web no matter the height and width given by user.

I try using jrac however it required me to save the cropped image before I show with  tag. Also I tried use pure css to complete this.

```
.crop {
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.crop img {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: -75px 0 0 -100px;
}
```

However the idea of css to crop image is just to hide the other part of the image and if I resize it as the original image. The other part appear again. I'm wondering what is the good approach to do so?

Comment: You could try playing around with background-size and background-position, and display the image as a background-image instead of an img tag.

Comment: what is "jrac" ?

Comment: jquery resize and crop library

Answer (score 1):

### CSS IMG Fill the container width/height. Recognize IMG aspect ratio.

**EDIT: I had to scrap the idea of using image orientation. Aspect Ratio makes more sense.**

This could work - Pictures are from wikimedia. One is vertical, second is horizontal. They are centered and fit to width/height.
I had to change `$(document).ready()` to `$(window).on("load")` - because the document ready waits only for HTML DOM to be fully loaded, but if images weren't downloaded yet, it would falsely recognize img dimensions and therefore its  aspect ratio (**EDIT**) .

### [image: Overflowing Aspect ratio demonstration]

- jQuery is used only to determine the Image Aspect ratio
- CSS centers the images inside the container element and resizes them
  according to the aspect ratio in comparison to the container.
- Cropping is done simply by containers `overflow:hidden`

```js
$(window).on("load",function() {//wait for images to be loaded
  $(".crop img").each(function() {//loop through images to be cropped
    if (($(this).width()/$(this).height()) < ($(this).parent().width()/$(this).parent().height()))//compare Aspect ratio
      $(this).addClass("taller");
  });
});
```

```css
body{padding:0;margin:0;}
.crop {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*hide "crop" overflowing parts of images*/
  border:1px solid #000;
}

.crop img {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /*center the overflowing element*/
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  /*Fit to height, overflow horizontally*/
  border:2px dashed red;
  /*highlight img borders for demonstration*/
}

.crop img.taller{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /*Fit to width, overflow vertically*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="crop">
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/82/Tyndall_Effect_seen_in_Nature.jpg">
</span>
<span class="crop">
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/81/WolayerSee.jpg/800px-WolayerSee.jpg">
</span>
<span class="crop" style="height:80px;">
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/81/WolayerSee.jpg/800px-WolayerSee.jpg">
</span>
```

Comment: if the container is wider than horizontal image, it wouldn't fill the whole area... I had to change the idea from comparing vertical/horizontal (portrait/landscape) orientation, to comparing aspect ratio of the image and the container... Determining whether the image is taller than the container.

Comment: In my case,the containers are fixed size the cropped image should adjust itself to fill the whole container.

Comment: @Pwan still that wouldn't help various input img aspect ratios... - Just use aspect ratio instead of orientation... It was mistake on my part.

Comment: Sorry I don't get you. the aspect ratios for image? what the whole process for the concept?

Comment: @Pwan Well my idea originally was just comparing wheter the image is portrait oriented or landscape... That works, but not in 100% of cases... When you compare the aspect ratio of the container and the aspect ratio of the image, you can determine if the image is taller and "resize" it according to that. - Determine if it's **Fit to Width** or **Fit to Height** - makes sense?

Comment: @Pwan If you find my answer sufficient, please consider marking it as solution. It can help others in the future and increase my rep. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Much cleaner solution suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/users/1034869/edmundo - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42714818/7581087

It is much cleaner and easier. On the other hand, it doesn't use `<img />` - which can possibly be bothersome.

```css
body{padding:0;margin:0;}
.crop {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 180px;
  height: 120px;
  background-position:center center;
  background-size:cover;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="crop" title="1st Image" style="background-image:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/82/Tyndall_Effect_seen_in_Nature.jpg)">
</span>
<span class="crop" title="2nd Image" style="background-image:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/81/WolayerSee.jpg/800px-WolayerSee.jpg)">
</span>
<span class="crop" title="3rd Image" style="height:80px;background-image:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/81/WolayerSee.jpg/800px-WolayerSee.jpg)">
</span>
<span class="crop" title="4th Image" style="width:50px;background-image:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/81/WolayerSee.jpg/800px-WolayerSee.jpg)">
</span>
```