# Bootstrap 4: responsive pictures + cropping?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I currently trying to learn bootstrap 4 from the scratch and was manage to deal quite ok with its limited documentation until now.

I put initial project here: http://codepen.io/kriszap/pen/GWWvLW
I'm particularly interested in this part:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 py-0 px-0 mx-0 my-0">
<img src="http://placehold.it/640x500" class="img-fluid">
</div>
```

I'd like to ask you for 2 simple questions:

1. when I resize window below 1200px, placeholder pictures scale down as intended (img-fluid class), but I'm looking for more elegant solution, i.e. http://html.orange-idea.com/barton/portfolio/smart/
   The above example looks to be too complicated for me, but I think the are using some kind of crop method? What I like here is that the image fill **100% of height**. Can this be done directly in bootstrap? Would you be so kind and suggest a SIMPLE solution for a beginner?
2. Is it a good practice to put the above image directly inside div class with columns? `(<div class="col-xxx">)`

Comment: Possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42642626/jquery-how-to-crop-a-image-and-scale-it-same-size-as-the-original-image/42642878#42642878 - This might help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you use background image for this with `background-size: cover`. See:

```css
.bg-cover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
  background: url("https://source.unsplash.com/7JX0-bfiuxQ/1200x1200") no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-cover">
</div>
```

You can learn more about the `background-size` property on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#Values

Comment: Mmm, this aproach seems very clean... I might use it in the future for responsive sliders - it would take away annoying js based resizing.

Comment: Hi Edmundo, your solution looks to be very elegant, but I struggle to make it work: http://codepen.io/kriszap/pen/GWWvLW.

Placehold image does not display, maybe I should add something in between  <div class="bg-cover"></div> tags?

Comment: Hi @KrisZap, your code seems to be working fine here. See screenshot: https://cloudup.com/cKjuvQpXUf9 You don't need to have anything within the `div.bg-cover`, you just need to set the dimensions (`width` & `height`) or `padding` – like you did with bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks, in another comment hunzaboy noticed that I was overriding background image with backround property in previous class. Thanks you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

**Your First Question:**

You can use the `background-size: cover;` as answered by edmundo.

**Your Second Question:**
Yes, you can put it inside col-**. It is as normal as it gets. However, to get the effect you want in the first question, I think you need to remove the image element and add it to your stylesheet and use it as a background image.

Comment: `add it to your stylesheet and use it as a background image` - not really, he can use it where it's needed simply by inline style `style="background-image:url(...)"` http://stackoverflow.com/a/42715016/7581087

Comment: I am not in favor of inline css.

Comment: When the HTML code is generated by web server how much does `<div><img src="pathToImage" /></div>` differ from `<div style="background-image:url(pathToImage)"></div>` - the amount of extra bytes is very low.

Comment: I like to keep styling separate from HTML. If you are going to change the background properties then it better to do them in the stylesheet. What ya say ?

Comment: If you choose this solution for slick responsive slider What are you gonna do? Generate new css file everytime you make a change to the slider?

Comment: JS can do whatever she wants :) . I gave CSS only solution.

Comment: so dynamically creating a `<style></style>` via JS that needs unique selector (probably elem ID) seems more effective than just setting the background-image inline to it's element on the server side? I give up here. I don't agree with that.

Comment: For me, yes. But again it changes with situation and type of page I am working on. You are bringing in lots of generic situations. If you see the question, there were 3-4 images. Why would i add inline css instead of keeping those in stylesheet and making my html cleaner?

Comment: I'm trying to learn from the scratch and in order to organize my css well I think it's better in a long term to keep it separate. Still thanks guys for your help!

Comment: @hunzaboy well if it's generated via CMS by a person that can't code - but will mange the content, manually changing the css file doesn't really look very user-friendly

Comment: @KrisZap that's what i think as well.

Comment: @AdamK., why are you diverting from the current question scenario? The user is a beginner and wants to learn. So why don't we direct him in a better way? He will be really confused right now :)

Comment: @KrisZap, Bottomline: Always keep your design related stuff in your stylesheet and use classes on HTML elements.

Comment: @hunzaboy there is no specification of the backoffice system nor the "server sided" experience of KrisZap. Yes - design related stuff in stylesheet - i do agree with that, but if it's a question of dynamic content, not design, then it won't apply to that. It was not specified if it's a matter of design or content though.

Comment: Guys when I think about it, for me as a beginner its really hard to keep my code (or markup if you like) clean. Just look at my initial example's CSS it's already pretty chaotic in structure. But this is always a compromise when one tries to learn and GET RESULTSas fast as possible... Are there any books/articles regarding keeping the code clean and structured?

Comment: Your html is Clean.

Comment: @KrisZap i don't think so - your code is organized well (There are large company websites, which html code is a mess) - over time and when you include more stuff in your web app (or static website) it becomes harder and harder to keep the code clean - so a lot of companies just give up on having a nice clean code.

Comment: Nice to hear that, but I just can't imagine keeping the structure of CSS file in a huge project. CSS is just so verbose for me sometimes...
And going back to initial answer: I still struggle to make it work: codepen.io/kriszap/pen/GWWvLW. Placehold image does not display, maybe I should add something in between <div class="bg-cover"></div> tags? Thanks

Comment: @KrisZap, just add the class to the col with the image.

Comment: @hunzaboy2: I feel like an idiot, but... still not working :/   
codepen.io/kriszap/pen/GWWvLW

Comment: http://codepen.io/hunzaboy/pen/EWWoyd You were overriding background image with backround property.

Comment: OMG it took me 5 minutes to find it... Thanks for all your help, works perfectly now!