# CSS ScaleY without stretch img children

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transforms

I have to show a list of image, but since a lot of them have a portrait aspect ratio I want to be able to show the images with smaller heigth, but not stretched, and when the user click them they will expand... I was able to do it changing the `max-height`, but the `transition` on mobile are very bad, so I want to use `transform` and `scaleY` to improve performance. The problem is that the image get stretched.

For example if this is the image, normal:

[image]

I want to make it to look like this, stretched:

[image]

And when the user click it the image return to the initial state.

This is my current code:

CSS

```css
.card img, .card video{
width: 100%;
vertical-align: middle;
border-radius:2px;
object-fit:cover;
will-change: max-height,height;
transition: max-height 0.4s ease;
}
```

HTML

```html
   <div class="card">
        <div>
            <img src="image.jpg"/>
        </div>
   </div>
```

And then in Javascript I simply set `maxHeight` of the `img` in `onclick` event.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42642626/jquery-how-to-crop-a-image-and-scale-it-same-size-as-the-original-image/42715016

Comment: Btw, the stretch can be solved just by using a lightbox.

Comment: But i have to use transform, otherwise the animations are stuttering and slow

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code

```
.image_container img {
margin: 0 auto;
object-fit: cover;
position: absolute;
top: 54%;
left: 50%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
max-height: none;
max-width: none;
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 100%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain how you can resize the image in javascript?